# How to store an OpenSSL signature to a file in ASN.1 format

Tags: openssl, asn.1

I'm implementing the "sign" step of an already hashed input `input_hash`. This can be done directly with

```
openssl pkeyutl -sign -in input_hash -inkey private.key -out signature
```

however I'm using an external device to calculate the response. This gives me a 64byte response that I have now managed to properly convert to the structure Openssl uses. This should be the `ECDSA_SIG` struct from `openssl/bn.h`

```c
struct ECDSA_SIG {
    BIGNUM *r;
    BIGNUM *s;
}
```

Next I would like to store this struct as a binary (DER) file using the proper ASN.1 format. However I am unable to find the proper function in the openssl library.

Note that I'm using an EC key, so using `openssl rsautl` tools is not an option. By looking at the output of the openssl command above i see the same structure I am trying to achieve.

```sh
$ openssl asn1parse -in signature -inform DER
0:d=0  hl=2 l=  69 cons: SEQUENCE
2:d=1  hl=2 l=  33 prim: INTEGER :E8229B1CF88EC5BC6E8270161E34D986FC8A5A7D5B2ED3B7C65BA808494E7030
37:d=1  hl=2 l=  32 prim: INTEGER :3FF76A6CB0210037C2D0F9075080E1B6461CDD8F52BB2374DB2B350E81C8A5C3
```

The only step missing now is storing my `ECDSA_SIG` structure to a file in the proper format. Otherwise the verification in openssl with the following command

```sh
openssl pkeyutl -verify -inkey public.key -sigfile signature -pkeyopt digest:sha256 -in input_hash -pubin
```

obviously fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the signature in an `ECDSA_SIG` structure then you can use the `i2d_ECDSA_SIG` function to convert it to DER format. Documented here:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/i2d_ECDSA_SIG.html